# <s:if> tag is not working struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have to check the condition like if the value is greater than 1.0, set class as red and if not, then class will be normal style. I tried the below code

```
<s:if test="%{plan.list[#p.index].val}>1.0">
    <span class="classRed">
        <s:property value="%{plan.list[#p.index].val}" escape="false" />
    </span>
</s:if>
<s:else>  
    <span>
        <s:property value="%{plan.list[#p.index].val}" escape="false" />
    </span>
</s:else>
```

Only the 'else' part is working. If I move the `classRed` portion to the 'else' section, then that will work. However, that's not the genuine solution. 
Am I making any syntax error ?

Answer (score 2):

The closing bracket was wrong
Instead of this

```
<s:if test="%{plan.list[#p.index].val}>1.0">
```

The following syntax worked

```
<s:if test="%{plan.list[#p.index].val>1.0}">
```

Comment: OGNL is an expression language: the *entire* expression  is bracketed, not just parts of it.